# set width and height to RNCamera

Tags: react-native

I'm a beginner in Rncamera, i just wanted to make the camera preview as a rectangle in the middle ( such a number scanner ).
my code is pretty simple

```
                 <RNCamera
                    ref={ref => {
                        this.camera = ref;
                    }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use camera',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    onTextRecognized={({textBlocks}) => {
                        if(textBlocks.length>0){
                            textBlocks.forEach(block => {
                                this.handleScan(block.value)
                            })
                        }
                    }}
                />
                <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)} style={styles.capture}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
```

i tried to set the width and the height as a style prop but it doesn't seem to work

```
preview: {
  flex: 1,
  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
  alignItems: 'center',
  height: 30,
  width: 400
},
```

Is there another way to do it ?